# Send name of portfolio item in Contact Form 7 Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i am in need of some help.

Simply said, i need a way to make a contact form (made with Contact Form 7 plugin) in Wordpress send the name of a portfolio item/page with the form as well.

Because there are artists that the customer can book, and then he needs to fill in the needed information in the form, but we also need to know which artist that customer wants to book, so is there a way to make my form also send the name of that artist/portfolio item. I'm using this same form on every artist page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this plugin, it can auto populate some fields, like the post ID and the post title: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/